# Flutter setState vs Bloc

Tags: flutter

I am newbiew Flutter learner. I want to create Flutter applications using setState.

I know most professional Flutter developers prefer to use Bloc pattern.

By now, I tried to find how to understand the Bloc approach, but I could not get far.

I still don't understand what the bloc approach is all about and how to implement it correctly.

if I don't use Bloc, then what apps I can develop using setState approach.

Could you please provide your thoughts.

Thank You

Comment: You can technically develop any app with `setState` and `InheritedWidget`, but you will run into a lot of maintainability issues. I recommend you go over the examples and understand what they describe.

Answer (score 0):

Bloc and setState are only app state management tools, nothing beyond that. Besides these, there are also MobX, Get, Riverpod, Provider, and Flutter Modular. My advice would be to become more familiar with the native Flutter's setState first. After that, you can try the others to see which one fits best or is more productive for you, as all of them are good and serve the same purpose, which is app state management. If possible, consider joining the [Flutter academy](https://novo.academiadoflutter.com.br/), which has a great community, and in the course, they will teach each of these tools.